# True seeing, can you see what you see past?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, illusion

When under the effects of true seeing, and you see past illusions and stuff, do you still see the other forms? So lets say people were using illusions as advertising banners, could you see the banners?

Comment: [Related] [Are Shadow Conjurations effectively invisible to True Seeing?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73004)

Comment: That question answers mine

Comment: @Fering: If you reload the page, you can use the dupe banner to confirm the dupe and close it immediately.

Comment: @TuggyNE I wasnt aware this site had a double tap required to finish the post like that, lol. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The spell description says the caster "sees through illusions".

This could be interpreted, as you have, as a literal seeing through to objects on the other side but an equally valid interpretation is that you see through the illusion metaphorically in that you know it is an illusion but it is still opaque. This interpretation has some support in the fact that the spell doesn't grant X-ray vision. The rules do not say which so this is a DM call.

Anyway, lets do it your way. You can see through something if it's translucent or if it's transparent. If it's translucent then you can still see it, if transparent you can't. The rules do not say which so this is a DM call.